# Put numbers to a star-shaped puzzle

Tags: mathematics, magic-square

[image]

For users who can not see picture, see description below

```
   Put numbers 1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10,11,12,13,14 (1 to 14, without 7)
   to each letter in such a way that the numbers in each row with 3 or 4
   letters in all three directions, sum the same constant X

      M 
   I J K L
    F G H
   B C D E
      A 

 B+C+D+E = F+G+H = I+J+K+L = B+F+J+M = C+G+K = A+D+H+L = I+F+C+A = J+G+D = M+K+H+E
```

Comment: I erase 7, and replace it with 14, because we cannot put numbers 1 to 13, to satisfy the puzzle.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This does it:

> For a constant sum of $28$
>
> ```
>          M                     3
>    I   J   K   L         9  10   8   1
>      F   G   H             2  14  12
>    B   C   D   E        13   6   4   5
>          A                    11
> ```

There may be other solutions beyond symmetry ...now to write some code

*new code for all valid solutions up to symmetry*

> There are $4$ solutions up to symmetry, all of which have a constant sum of $28$, have $14$ in their centre, and have tips that sum to $14$ This code runs within the second
>
> ```
> from itertools import combinations, permutations
>
> def f():
>     numbers = [i for i in range(1,7)]+[i for i in range(8,15)]
>     for g in numbers:
>         woG = set(numbers)
>         woG.discard(g)
>         for jd in combinations(woG, 2):
>             for j, d in permutations(jd):
>                 woGJD = set(woG)
>                 woGJD.discard(j)
>                 woGJD.discard(d)
>                 x = g + j + d
>                 xMG = j + d
>                 for fh in combinations(woGJD, 2):
>                     for f, h in permutations(fh):
>                         if f + h == xMG:
>                             woGJDFH = set(woGJD)
>                             woGJDFH.discard(f)
>                             woGJDFH.discard(h)
>                             for kc in combinations(woGJDFH, 2):
>                                 for k, c in permutations(kc):
>                                     if k + c == xMG:
>                                         woGJDFHKC = set(woGJDFH)
>                                         woGJDFHKC.discard(k)
>                                         woGJDFHKC.discard(c)
>                                         for ila in combinations(woGJDFHKC, 3):
>                                             for i, l, a in permutations(ila):
>                                                 if i + l + j + k == x and a + d + h + l == x and a + c + f + i == x:
>                                                     woGJDFHKCILA = set(woGJDFHKC)
>                                                     woGJDFHKCILA.discard(i)
>                                                     woGJDFHKCILA.discard(l)
>                                                     woGJDFHKCILA.discard(a)
>                                                     m, e, b = woGJDFHKCILA
>                                                     if m < l and m + e + k + h == x and b + c + d + e == x and b + f + j + m == x:
>                                                         yield (m,i,j,k,l,f,g,h,b,c,d,e,a), x
>
> def printStar(m,i,j,k,l,f,g,h,b,c,d,e,a):
>     print('''      {0:>2}
> {1:>2}  {2:>2}  {3:>2}  {4:>2}
>   {5:>2}  {6:>2}  {7:>2}
> {8:>2}  {9:>2}  {10:>2}  {11:>2}
>       {12:>2}'''.format(m,i,j,k,l,f,g,h,b,c,d,e,a))
> ```
>
> Like so:
>
> ```
> >>> for star, s in pre():
> ...     print(s)
> ...     printStar(*star)
> ...
> 28
>        3
>  6  13   5   4
>    2  14  12
> 10   9   1   8
>       11
> 28
>        2
>  5  13   6   4
>    3  14  11
> 10   8   1   9
>       12
> 28
>        1
>  5  12   8   3
>    4  14  10
> 11   6   2   9
>       13
> 28
>        1
>  6  11   9   2
>    4  14  10
> 12   5   3   8
>       13
> ```

*previous slow, non-symmetry "naive" search*

> Yes there are other solutions beyond symmetry - this code will not be fast, but it produces others quite quickly that are not mere reflections and/or rotations:
>
> ```
> from itertools import permutations
>
> def f():
>     for m,i,j,k,l,f,g,h,b,c,d,e,a in permutations([i for i in range(1,7)]+[i for i in range(8,15)]):
>         x = b+c+d+e
>         if x == f+g+h and x == i+j+k+l and x == b+f+j+m and x == c+g+k and x == a+d+h+l and x == i+f+c+a and x == j+g+d and x == m+k+h+e:
>             yield (m,i,j,k,l,f,g,h,b,c,d,e,a), x
>
> def printStar(m,i,j,k,l,f,g,h,b,c,d,e,a):
>     print('''      {0:>2}
> {1:>2}  {2:>2}  {3:>2}  {4:>2}
>   {5:>2}  {6:>2}  {7:>2}
> {8:>2}  {9:>2}  {10:>2}  {11:>2}
>       {12:>2}'''.format(m,i,j,k,l,f,g,h,b,c,d,e,a))
> ```
>
> Starting off like so:
>
> ```
> >>> for star, s in f():
> ...     print(s)
> ...     printStar(*star)
> ...
> 28
>        1
>  2   9  11   6
>   10  14   4
>  8   3   5  12
>       13
> 28
>        1
>  3   8  12   5
>   10  14   4
>  9   2   6  11
>       13
> ```
>
> The second is isomorphic to the one I gave before, but the first is not.

Comment: how do you approach it?

Comment: @numberknot I just went for 28 and shuffled them around, nothing inspired :(

Comment: Well, there is a lot of structure in your solution. Odd numbers on the tips, even in the middle. Pairs that sum to 14 on opposite sides, with the single 14 in the middle. I wouldn't be surprised that if there are other solutions, they have the same properties,

Comment: @JaapScherphuis yeah - we can rotate and/or reflect this one at least!

Comment: @JaapScherphuis - found an hetero-morphic solution, opposite tips summing to 14 may be a necessary condition, but even in the middle is not.

Comment: I ran my own program, and there are only 4 solutions apart from  rotations/reflections. All have 14 in the middle, and the rest of the numbers in pair that sum to 14, for a magic number of 28. They are {1/2/9/11/6/10/14/4/8/3/5/12/13}, {1/3/8/12/5/10/14/4/9/2/6/11/13}, {2/4/6/13/5/11/14/3/9/1/8/10/12}, {3/4/5/13/6/12/14/2/8/1/9/10/11}. The first two are the ones you already found.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis - I can see that from my (now) 12, I can't quite figure out how to cater for the rotations in my code as it stands without adding them to a set and checking (which will be fast but unsatisfactory)... maybe post it!!

Comment: I filtered my solutions by hand, simply by discarding all where A is larger than B, E, L, I, or M (for rotations), and all where B>E (for reflections). My program is a generic program that I wrote to solve (almost) all the edge-matching tile puzzles that I have, and is too large and idiosyncratic to be shared with others.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis - Ah, fair enough! I ended up doing a similar filter - I go through all inner permutations, then all permutations of one equilateral triangle of the points and leave the rest in a single order, then only yield results where one pair of points across the two triangles are ordered (I chose M < L to have the top points minimal - which matches your solutions above).